# listbox, textbox and button in c#

Tags: c#, button, textbox, listbox

So I'm working on a Security panel in c# on visual studio and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to take information from the textbox and if it is a certain code it will display something else in the listbox.

For example, you click buttons 1,2,4,5 and then hit the # button, it should display the date, time and a message explaining who has accessed through the security panel so a message like:

"10/22/13 5:21 Security Team"

```
        private void btnHASH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        accessboxLIST.Items.Add(codeTXT.Text);
        codeTXT.Clear();           

    }
```

Is the button that enters whatever is in the textbox and puts that in the listbox but that isn't what I need, I need it to display a different message

In total there are 12 buttons, with the texts 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,C,#
btnHASH = #

a successful code like what I stated before being 1245 should display in the listbox the Date, Time and the message "Security Team"

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your code please.

Comment: please read [ask].  You should have a minimum understanding of the issue and post relevant code to your issue.  Try reading some introductions to wpf like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99330/WPF-Step-by-Step-Getting-Started-with-WPF-and-Expr)

Comment: Let's try to break this down a bit into manageable questions. It looks like you want to construct a string, for this I'd recommend learning how to use `String.Format`. You want to be able to get the values from controls, look at MSDN docs to look at what properties they have... a `TextBox` for example, will have a `.Text` property you can use. It looks like you also want to handle events, like the button clicked event... do some research on how to handle button click events. Try searching for answers to those individual questions and see if that gets you on your way.

Comment: im continuing to edit my question with parts of what i've got done, im just really confused

Comment: Good. If the buttons are really toggling state (i.e. do I want to show or not show "X"), you probably want to use a `CheckBox` instead. This type of question, since it is so specific to your scenario and vary broad probably doesn't belong in StackOverflow. Rather, I'd recommend maybe going to the C# chatroom (you don't have enough rep to talk there now) to get some pointers on specific points you're having trouble with.

Comment: For this assignment I have to use a listbox, when the button # is clicked, and the code in the textbox is a valid code it should display the date, time and a certain message that describes who entered aka security team, janitor etc

Answer (score 0):

> For this assignment I have to use a listbox, when the button # is
>   clicked, and the code in the textbox is a valid code it should display
>   the date, time and a certain message that describes who entered aka
>   security team, janitor etc

OK...so hopefully the code behind your digit buttons looks something like these:

```
    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        codeTXT.Focus();
        codeTXT.SelectedText = "0";
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        codeTXT.Focus();
        codeTXT.SelectedText = "1";
    }

    // ...etc...
```

Then, when # is pressed, you need to check the .Text() property of codeTXT:

```
    private void btnHASH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (codeTXT.Text == "1245")
        {
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Security Team");
            codeTXT.Clear();
        }
        else if (codeTXT.Text == "007")
        {
            accessboxLIST.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " James Bond");
            codeTXT.Clear();
        }
    }
```